# Error while installing cakePHP on LAMP (CentOS 7 VM)

Tags: cakephp, lamp, centos7

I am trying to install cakePHP  over LAMP on a centos 7 VM, but getting this error. I'm not sure why i am getting this error i have made app/tmp file writable.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in /var/www/html/phtagr/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:181 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/phtagr/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_') #1 /var/www/html/phtagr/Config/core.php(420): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array) #2 /var/www/html/phtagr/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72): include('/var/www/html/p...') #3 /var/www/html/phtagr/cakephp/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(177): Configure::bootstrap(true) #4 /var/www/html/phtagr/webroot/index.php(129): include('/var/www/html/p...') #5 /var/www/html/phtagr/index.php(25): require('/var/www/html/p...') #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/phtagr/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 181
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give write permission `tmp` and `logs` folder of your project
if folder not exist then you have to create and add permission at
`/tmp`
`/logs`

Details check [Here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#permissions)

Comment: I have given 777 permissions to tmp and Logs and even tried giving 777 to  whole project folder but still getting the error.

Comment: You have to set permission recursively @jarus plz try it

Comment: yup tried recursively the whole folder chmod -R 777 myProject

Comment: @trikul05 I got rid of the error, had to disable SELINUX

Comment: Thank you though :) @trikul05